# How do I prevent screen artifacts in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having issues with parts of sheets showing even though they are not the active sheet in Excel(both 2013 and 2015).

I'm writing some data capture and reporting tools using Excel and VBA.  My system generates sheets and populates them with formatted tables that the user can enter data into. After the user has finished it takes that data does some processing and generates one or more new sheets with extra charts and tables, all paginated nicely for printing.

[image: Example Screen Artifacts - While showing sheet A, excel displays some cells from sheet B]

In the above screenshot the Data Entry table was happily displaying normally until I started trying to select from the validation list in C14, at which point row 9 decided to disappear and let the contents of the next sheet show through.  You can see the columns don't line up properly.  This happens at other points as well, particularly after the initial generation of the data entry sheet.

I don't know if this is related, but a set of ActiveX CommandButtons that I have on a Welcome sheet and show and enable at various points throughtout the process don't always update correctly. Sometimes they won't appear after being shown (despite the fact that reading the properties via the Watch window suggests that Visible is True); sometimes they will display as disabled while enabled is true (they are in fact still clickable, though it is not very helpful from a User's perspective).

Switching sheets, minimising and restoring the program and typing into a cell all sometimes fix these problems.

I do set `Application.ScreenUpdating` appropriately, setting it True before any sheet generation routines then false afterwards.

Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?  Alternatively, how do I trigger a screen redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes if one writes a loop that uses much of the system resources, this can prevent the screen to update properly. If you insert the command **DoEvents** in this loop (I usually puts it on top), then this frees up the computer to do screen refreshing, and prevents the sheet to freeze up util the calculation is done. have you tried the the DoEvents command ?

Comment: I did know about this, but because it was occuring outside of my looping table-generation logic I'd discounted it.  It seems that it does manage to fix the issue of spreadsheets showing through one another, which was my main issue.  It doesn't help for my side issue of my commandbuttons not updating properly though.

Answer (score 0):

`DoEvents` often doesn't work for me, especially for command buttons.  Here's what I use to clear up screen artifacts including:

- Apparent split in window where none actually exists
- Ghost command buttons from other worksheets

`Sub ClearScreenArtifacts()`

```
    DoEvents

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
        .ActiveWindow.SmallScroll up:=1
        .WindowState = .WindowState
    End With


    ' Toggle Screen Updating
    With Application
        Dim updatingState As Boolean
        updatingState = .ScreenUpdating

        .ScreenUpdating = Not updatingState
        .ScreenUpdating = updatingState
    End With


    ' Toggle Freeze Panes
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ActiveWindow
        ' Remember currently selected range
        Dim originalSelection As Range
        Set originalSelection = Application.Selection

        ' Freeze panes below 1st row.
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        ws.Range("A2").Select
        .FreezePanes = True

        ' Freeze panes at last row.
        .FreezePanes = False
        ws.Range("A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Select
        .FreezePanes = True

        ' Unfreeze panes.
        .FreezePanes = False
        .Split = False

        ' Re-select original selected range
        originalSelection.Select
    End With
```

`End Sub`

Comment: You can just say `Application.Screenupdating = TRUE` or `Application.Screenupdating = FALSE`.  Less verbose, same effect.

Comment: Yes @n8. that would be less verbose.  I intentionlly did it this way to force Excel to change the ScreenUpdating property while returning that property to the state it was originally in.  So if screen updating is -OFF- to begin with, it will toggle it -ON-, then -OFF-.  If it's -ON- to begin with, it will toggle it -OFF- then back -ON-.

Comment: So basically you're going through and fiddling the knobs :P

Comment: Every last one : )